# Why is isFrontend set differently for Profile in create mode vs HTML snippet?

Tags: ajax

I had trouble with ajax Country / State dropdowns in a profile used as an HTML snippet embedded in a Joomla page.  The dropdowns worked fine in the profile in create mode.  I realized that the HTML snippet defines isFrontend as "false", whereas the create mode defines it as 1.

When set to "false", the query for a list of states upon a country change tries to access the administrator area, which fails because of authentication problems.  Changing the HTML snippet code to set isFrontend to 1 fixes that problem.

Is there a reason it's set to "false"?  Am I in danger of breaking something else?  Is this a bug in the generated HTML snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is most likely a bug in the html snippet generator. Changing the snippet is indeed the solution to your problem, and as long as it works for your form no I wouldn't worry about that change causing problems.